# SQL Server 2012 Failover Cluster: moving roles between nodes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, cluster-computing

We've got two physical servers dedicated for SQL Server 2012 in single cluster (`SQL1`, `SQL2` and `CLUSTER` respectively). This setup had few instances of SQL Server 2012: default (`MSSQLSERVER`) and three named ones (let's say `NORTH`, `EAST` and `SOUTH`).

They all were functioning on `SQL1` node. But one day some lad cut off power to node `SQL1` by accident and I saw this: `MSSQLSERVER`, `EAST` and `SOUTH` switched to `SQL2` without problem, but `NORTH` didn't. When `SQL1` was online again I've started it's **"SQL Server (NORTH)"** role by hand. But when I tried to move that role to `SQL2`, it failed again with message something about 'cluster node is not owner of that group and cannot become one'.

This cluster setup was not made by me so it's quite difficult for me to say if `NORTH` is something different then the rest instances. It should be like `SOUTH` and `EAST` in every aspect, actually. Currently default, `SOUTH` and `EAST` are running on `SQL2` and `NORTH` on `SQL1`

**Some other info:**

**STORAGE:**

- SQL1 currently owns only NORTH disk (Cluster Disk 2)
- SQL2 currently owns drives for default instance (Cluster Disk 1), EAST (Cluster Disk 5), SOUTH (Cluster Disk 7), quorum (Cluster Disk 4) and all other volumes, which are empty and for future.

**SERVICES:**

Among SQL1 services I see all SQL instance related services: for MSSQLSERVER, NORTH, SOUTH and EAST, all but NORTH are stopped.

Among SQL2 services I see MSSQLSERVER, SOUTH and EAST running, but no sign of NORTH, not even stopped one.

Can someone tell what could it be or what was done wrong with this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it looks like the NORTH instance is not installed at SQL2. So you need to run SQL Server setup on it to add this node to a cluster.

Comment: So I need to move all roles to SQL1, then kick SQL2 out of cluster, install that instance separately on SQL2 and then add SQL2 to cluster?

Comment: No, just failover all SQL Server instances to SQL1, then install NORTH instance on SQL2 with special mode of SQL Server setup program. See here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191545.aspx